# how to add css padding for button such that it is consistent with column width?

Tags: html, css, web, padding

i'm having this problem where i cannot make the padding of a button constant with the column width. it is necessary for me because when a user is to hover onto the button, it changes background. but if i use a static value for the button padding width, it will get distorted once anyone zooms in our out two three levels. i tried to use the values as %, but to no avail. help will be much appreciated!

you may easily try out my code on ur own pc and see what i'm talking about:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <title>Welcome!</title>
    <!--<link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

    <center>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="header">
            </div>
            <div id="menupane">
                <center><a href="#" class="buttons">Home</a></center>
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>

</body>

</html>
```

css:

```
#main
{
    width: 80%;
    height: 590px
}

#header
{
    background-color: #1f3568;
    height: 12%;
}

#menupane
{
    background-color: #cfd3db;
    height: 85%;
    width: 8%;
    float: left;
}

.buttons
{
    color: #1f3568;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 0px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.buttons:hover
{
    background-color: #677ba7;
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: can you add this to jsfiddle and share the link.

Comment: The `<center>` tag is deprecated. use `text-align:center;` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display:block` to `.buttons` to fill the width of its parent

```
.buttons
{
    display:block;
    text-align:center; // removed CENTER element
    color: #1f3568;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 0px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RRS7n/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do. I would remove the  and update my CSS. And like Don said that  tag is deprecated. Update this on your page and let me know if this is what you want.

**HTML Update:**

```
<div id="menupane">
  <a href="#" class="buttons">Home</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#menupane
{
    background-color: #cfd3db;
    height: 85%;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}

a.buttons
{
    display:block;
    color: #1f3568;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

a.buttons:hover
{
    background-color: #677ba7;
}
```

Comment: yep, that is similar to the answer Daniel Gimenez posted earlier. thanks